# VueJS: Using static HTML files

Tags: vue.js

I'm quite new to Vue and I'm building a web panel for which I need a login page. However, since that login has nothing to do with the single page web panel that I am building (in terms of look, navigation, etc), and it uses a completely different template, I want to encapsulate it in a completely distinct static HTML file.

How can I serve a static HTML file next to the default `Index.Html` in Vue? Is that even possible?

Comment: It's only a matter of your server delivering that file.

Comment: @connexo: The problem is that, when I pass the URL to that file, it automatically becomes a part of the `/#/` path. And yeah it does not work.

Comment: if you are using webpack you can pre-render static HTML files for specific routes . Check out ; https://github.com/chrisvfritz/prerender-spa-plugin

Comment: @VamsiKrishna: not interested in plugins, I prefer a pure Vue solution just to prevent conflicts in the future

Comment: @Arrrr are you using webpack?

Comment: @VamsiKrishna: Yeah

Comment: The login page has nothing to do with vue?

Comment: @VamsiKrishna: No, I only sends an ajax request to get authentication token and save it in browser memory. The vue app will then rely on the token.

Comment: @Arrrr That's really bad design.

Comment: @connexo: Any idea to standardize it?

Comment: @connexo: A web panel, is just a component that needs to be single page, but the rest of the web app is not single page. Or maybe I need two single page panels within an ASP.Net Core app. That's why I designed it that way.

Comment: I solved my problem by https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder

Answer (score 10):

You can use static **assets** folder for that task.

## vue cli 2.x

There are two assets folders by default: `static` ("Real" Static Assets) in app root and `src/assets` (Webpacked Assets)

The first one is what you can use, i think. Quote from https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/static.html

> In comparison, files in `static/` are not processed by Webpack at all:
>   they are directly copied to their final destination as-is, with the
>   same filename. You must reference these files using absolute paths,
>   which is determined by joining `build.assetsPublicPath` and
>   `build.assetsSubDirectory` in config.js.

Any static assets and html too can be placed here, why not. They can be accessed using absolute paths, for example in dev environment and default config:

`http://localhost:8080/static/login.html`

## vue cli 3

There is some changes in new vue cli version. "Real" static assets directory (not processed by Webpack) now is `public`. Quotes from: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#static-assets-handling

> **Static Assets Handling Static assets can be handled in two different ways:**
>
> - Imported in JavaScript or referenced in templates/CSS via relative paths. Such references will be handled by webpack.
> - Placed in the `public` directory and referenced via absolute paths. These assets will simply be copied and not go through webpack.

Also check this recommendation!:

> Note we recommend importing assets as part of your module dependency
>   graph so that they will go through webpack with the following
>   benefits:
>
> - Scripts and stylesheets get minified and bundled together to avoid
>     extra network requests.
> - Missing files cause compilation errors instead
>     of 404 errors for your users.
> - Result filenames include content hashes
>     so you don’t need to worry about browsers caching their old versions.
>
> **When to use the public folder**
>
> - You need a file with a specific name in the build output.
> - You have thousands of images and need to dynamically reference their paths.
> - Some library may be incompatible with Webpack and you have no other option but to include it as a `<script>` tag.

Comment: What if I don't want the `static` to be part of the path? This isn't a good solution although that I may work.

Comment: This is clearly the best answer and helped me get a quick static HTML file served per the question.  Deserves some upvotes.

Comment: copy pasta and the static file is not included in the webpack dependency graph, so expect 404s...

Answer (score 0):

What you want to accomplish should be done in the backend.

Pseudocode:

```
if (user.isLoggedin) {
   res.send('vue/index.html')
} else {
   res.send('loginpanel/index.html')
}
```

This way you will have the same `path` for both sites.

The implementation details of the backend are dependent of your selected tech stack.